# How to save the NEW Entity which has parent relation with the Existing Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

If I run the code below, I got an exception.

> In order to update the AssociationSet 'x', the corresponding entity from EntitySet 'x' must be available in the ObjectStateManager.

Here is my code. No matter I add the client to the Users entityset or not, I still get the error.

```
        MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();
        //create new client entity
        ClientUser client = new ClientUser();
        client.UID = 9;
        client.UserName = "KKL";
        client.CompanyName = "KKL Company";

        //retrieve existing entity
        AdminUser admin = db.Users.OfType<AdminUser>().FirstOrDefault();
        //assign AdminUser of new client to existing admin
        client.AdminUser = admin;

        //db.Users.AddObject(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I tried to save the New Entity first, then add relation and save again. But it's showing same error message. :(

```
        MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities();
        //create new client entity
        ClientUser client = new ClientUser();
        client.UID = 9;
        client.UserName = "KKL";
        client.CompanyName = "KKL Company";

        //first save the new object
        db.Users.AddObject(client);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //retrieve existing entity
        AdminUser admin = db.Users.OfType<AdminUser>().FirstOrDefault();
        client.AdminUser = admin;

        db.SaveChanges();
```

**SOLVE!!!**

My problem is in association.

I have 0..1 relationship at both ends between ClientUser and AdminUser.

**Admin (0..1) < -- > Client (0..1)**

And I've already assigned that admin user to another existing client. Then I tried to create new client and assign that admin and it raise the errors.

I fixed it by changing the relationship as below

**Admin (0..1) < -- > Client (*)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using poco objects the problem will be with the way that you've created the ClientUser.  You need to create the new ClientUser within the current context:

```
ClientUser client = _myObjectContext.CreateObject<ClientUser>();
```